# Problem with rendering data from backend React js, Spring HATEOAS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a problem with fetching data from the backend. when I try to render data from the backend I have the error

```
Portfolio.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'self')
at Portfolio.render (Portfolio.js:34:1)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485:1)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

The code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { MDBCard, MDBCardImage, MDBCardBody, MDBCardTitle, MDBCardText, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBContainer, MDBRipple, MDBCardOverlay, MDBCardLink } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ThemeConsumer } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/ThemeProvider';


export default class Portfolio extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
          photoAlboums:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/photo-albums/1")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({photoAlboums: response.data});
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <p>{this.state.photoAlboums._links.self.href}</p>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The data

```
{"id":1,"name":"Photo studio","_links"
:{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/api/photo-albums/1"},
"photoAlbums":{"href":"http://localhost:8081/api/photo-albums/list"}}}
```

But when I render the name of data, everything works.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: typo - `{this.state.photoAlboums._links.self.href}` compare with `photoAlbums`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to get data out of an array as an object. you will need to update you code to be able to take in the array items. see example below.

Change your code to:

```
{this.state.photoAlboums.length > 0 && 
  this.state.photoAlboums.map((photo) => {
    <div>
      <p>{photo._links.self.href}</p>
    </div>

 } )
```

Also check your typos.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have this.state.photoAlboums.length = 0. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the length is 0? you need to use this '==='. it will check the equality.